# How to assign attributes to child element?

Tags: html, css

How do I specifically assign a style to a child (the top black header from the image)

I've tried something like

> .noo-topbar > .container > a

and

> .noo-topbar .container a

but nothing's changed...

[view from Google Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixbnn.jpg)

Comment: can you make a fiddle and also tell us specifically which element you are trying to access then we can help you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
.noo-topbar .container > ul li a
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about css combinators:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp

if you still have trouble i'd suggest applying an id to it, like #specialElement, and styling it directly.